# PHP Calling A Class function inside B Class

Tags: php, class, oop

I Want to access a function outside of the class in another file, another class , thanks for all help!

file "a" class "a" function "a"  --> file "b" class "b" function "b" (I want to use function "a" in this)

```
//file : a.php
class A 
{
public function a($string)
   {
     $string .= $string; // Not static 
     return $string;
   }

}
//file : b.php
require_once('a.php');


class B
{
public function b($string)
   {
     //here I need function "a"
     $string = a($string);
     return $string;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File a.php:

```
<?php
class A 
{
    public function a($string='')
    {
        $string .= $string; // Not static 
        return $string;
    }
}
```

File b.php:

```
<?php
require_once('a.php');

class B
{
    public function b($string='')
    {
        $aObj = new A();
        
        //here I need function "a"
        $string = $aObj->a($string);
        return $string;
    }

}
```